# How can I output several variables into one message in telegram bot?

Tags: telebot

I'm learning to make telegram bots and currently I'm trying to write a weather bot.
The problem is, that when I'm trying to output both, temperature and weather in one message, it sends me an error 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str' and I have no idea how to fix this.

```
import telebot
import requests
import json

bot = telebot.TeleBot('...')
api = '...'


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Tell me the city name')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_weather(message):
    city = message.text.strip().lower()
    res = requests.get(f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={api}&units=metric')
    if res.status_code == 200:
        data = json.loads(res.text)
        temp = data["main"]["temp"]
        conditions = data["weather"]["main"]
        bot.reply_to(message, f'️Current temperature is: {temp}\n Current weather is: {conditions}')
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'City not found')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

I've tried to put temperature and weather into separate variables and I get the same error 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import telebot
import requests
import json

bot = telebot.TeleBot('...')
api = '...'

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Tell me the city name')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_weather(message):
    city = message.text.strip().lower()
    res = requests.get(f'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={api}&units=metric')
    if res.status_code == 200:
        data = json.loads(res.text)
        temp = data["main"]["temp"]
        conditions = data["weather"][0]["main"]  # Access the first element of the list
        bot.reply_to(message, f'️Current temperature is: {temp}\n Current weather is: {conditions}')
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'City not found')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```